# Exporting to Excel with additional headings

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net

I have a button which exports to Excel perfectly, however i would like to include headings above the data cells on excel, eg. Report name, Period etc

How do i go about doing this ? My export code is below

```
Protected Sub btnexp_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexp.Click

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    gv1.AllowPaging = False

    Call btnsubmit_Click(sender, e)

    'Change the Header Row back to white color 
    gv1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")

    'Apply style to Individual Cells 
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "white")
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "white")
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "white")
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "white")
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(4).Style.Add("background-color", "white")
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(5).Style.Add("background-color", "white")
    gv1.HeaderRow.Cells(6).Style.Add("background-color", "white")


    For i As Integer = 0 To gv1.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim row As GridViewRow = gv1.Rows(i)

        'Change Color back to white 
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

        'Apply text style to each Row 
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")

        'Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row 
        If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            row.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            row.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            row.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            row.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            row.Cells(4).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            row.Cells(5).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")
            row.Cells(6).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")

        End If

    Next

    gv1.RenderControl(hw)

    'style to format numbers to string 
    Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"

    Response.Write(style)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()

End Sub
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)

    ' Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time.

End Sub
```

Comment: are these headings going to be taken from the column descriptions of the gridview? If so, loop through the columns collection of the gridview and extract the names, and add cells into your spreadsheet for them.

Comment: Nope, the headings will be taken from session values. The gridview from my form will be exported as normal, however a couple cells above the exported table in Excel i would require a few headings.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _

    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim x As Integer


        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

        For x = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, x + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(x).HeaderText
        Next

        For i = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\vbexcel.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

        MsgBox("You can find the file C:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: only issue I can think of is interop will require Excel (or at least some of the DLLs) installed on the server, and not all server hosting environments allow this. Also COM interop in general is a bit legacy and is not hugely reliable for a server-based app. There are other libraries such as EppPlus and many others which can do the same job without requiring a COM interface to the Excel application.